# Python inheritance from lists

Tags: python, inheritance

I just started learning Python, and created the following class, that inherits from list:

```
class Person(list):
    def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_books=[]):
        #person initialization code
        list.__init__(a_books)
        self.name = a_name
        self.dob = a_dob
```

However, there are three things I don't understand:

1. This line `list.__init__(a_books)`, doesn't actually initialize my instance's list of books.
2. I am supposed, according to the book, write `list.__init__([])` instead. Why is this step necessary.
3. Why is there no reference to `self` in `list.__init__([])`? How does Python know?

Comment: For a practical system you probably want list to be an attribute of Person rather then inherit from list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a [`super` call to instantiate the object using the parents `__init__` method first](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html):

```
class Person(list):
    def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_books=[]):
        #person initialization code
        super(Person, self).__init__(a_books)
        self.name = a_name
        self.dob = a_dob

print Person('bob',a_books=['how to bob'])
```

[Gives the output](https://ideone.com/pwI3jM):

> ```
> ['how to bob']
> ```

Because `list` has a `__str__` method.